# Cookie nonce is invalid - Multisite

Tags: multisite, ajax, wp-admin, security

I get following messages:

Applicaiton password plugin

> Cookie nonce is invalid

iThemes Security

> A nonce security check failed, preventing the request from completing as expected. Please try reloading the page and trying again.

...when I try to save settings in network (subdirectory multisite) admin. But I don't get this messages if I use the settings panel for a plugin within a site.

I did some debugging and what I found was that [wp_verify_nonce()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce) always returns false. The cookie token never match the expected token. I have no idea why Wordpress is behaving in this way.

Do someone have an idea why Wordpress nonce is behaving in this way? How can I fix it?

I'm using Bedrock and here is my settings:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://my-local-cms.dev');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://my-local-cms.dev/backend');
define('CONTENT_DIR', '/app');

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');

define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'my-local-cms.dev');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

The links to the Network Admin are incorrect. For example, network users have:

> http://my-local-cms.dev/wp-admin/network/

It should be (if wordpress core is located in backend/)

> http://my-local-cms.dev/backend/wp-admin/network/

If you visit the first link and add /backend/ before wp-admin in the browser, then the network admin will behave correctly.

**Fix**

*Edit 2017-08-30*
New solution:

```
public function fix_network_admin_url($path, $scheme) {
    $path = ltrim($path, '/');
    return str_replace('/wp-admin/network', '/backend/wp-admin/network', $path);
}
add_filter('network_admin_url','fix_network_admin_url', 10, 3);
```

*end of 2017-08-30 edit*

The way I chose to solve this is to make a separate network admin menu with corrected links. This is not an elegant solution, <s>but I don't know how to fix the URLs only for the native Network Admin menu and leave the rest of the links intact (see "Other potential solutions")</s>.

My solution is similar to this (add to either to function.php in theme or create a plugin):

```
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_head_network_menu');
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'custom_network_admin_bar_menu', 20);

function admin_head_network_menu()
{
    echo '<style type="text/css">#wp-admin-bar-my-sites-super-admin {display: none}</style>';
}

function custom_network_admin_bar_menu($adminBar)
{
    // Don't add network admin bar for non super admins
    if (!current_user_can('manage_network')) {
        return;
    }

    $mainMenuID = 'my-new-network-admin-menu';

    $adminBar->add_menu([
        'id' => $mainMenuID,
        'title' => __('Network Admin'),
        'href' => new_admin_url(),
    ]);

    $adminBar->add_menu([
        'id' => $mainMenuID.'-sites',
        'parent' => $mainMenuID,
        'title' => __('Network Sites'),
        'href' => new_admin_url('sites.php'),
    ]);

    $adminBar->add_menu([
        'id' => $mainMenuID.'-users',
        'parent' => $mainMenuID,
        'title' => __('Network Users'),
        'href' => new_admin_url('users.php'),
    ]);

    $adminBar->add_menu([
        'id' => $mainMenuID.'-plugins',
        'parent' => $mainMenuID,
        'title' => __('Network Plugins'),
        'href' => new_admin_url('plugins.php'),
    ]);

    $adminBar->add_menu([
        'id' => $mainMenuID.'-settings',
        'parent' => $mainMenuID,
        'title' => __('Network Settings'),
        'href' => new_admin_url('settings.php'),
    ]);
}

function new_admin_url($path = '')
{
    $url = network_admin_url($path);
    return str_replace('/wp-admin/network', '/backend/wp-admin/network', $url);
}
```

**Other potential solutions**

If you have a (sub)domain multisite installation, checkout "felixarntz/multisite-fixes" on Github (mu-plugins/wpms-site-url-fixer.php).

I think maybe this can be fixed with a change in .htaccess. For number of reasons this was not an option for my project. But if someone else want to have a go, here is an example .htaccess for Bedrock:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```